# Regular Expression construction for plain text using Python

Tags: python, regex

I have a text format as given below, I need to extract the text using Regular expression, for each key I have a **3digit** number which can be useful to extract the text.I'm able to extract the text also with that logic. please help me to fetch the values from other the below lines also till I get the next **digit** or : symbol.

**Sample text document**

```
200 Testresults:
Negative - blood sample shows a negative result 



200 study: lung issues
Disease code: 1#0045252452



200 Comments: 
Results should be tezted for the confirmation of Covid-19 with the assigned physican 
samples have been attached in the report 


200 Date: 02/05/2020
```

**RE: Sample code**

```
newtext = re.compile(r'^\d{3} [a-z].*')
```

**Required Json**

```
{"Testresults":"Negative - blood sample shows a negative result ","study":"lung issues","Comments":"Results should be tezted for the confirmation of Covid-19 with the assigned physican samples have been attached in the report","Date":"02/05/2020"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will give you what you need

```
dict(re.findall('^\d{3} ([A-Za-z].*):\s+(.*)', input, re.MULTILINE))
```

https://regex101.com/r/FsC6j8/1

Comment: @lain Shelvington .. This is exactly working fine , but my issues is I need to read the data from other lines to  Comments section should capture both the lines